# Problema de ruta "src" para cargar imagen(archivo), wordpress, error 404,

Tags: php, wordpress, rutas, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Estoy creando un tema para wordpress y tengo un problema con las imágenes que puse en el archivo `footer.php`. Como saben el `header` y `footer` de la pagina web se muestra en todas las paginas y entradas.

**El problema es:** esas imágenes de `footer.php` solo se muestran en la portada; ósea  cuando elijo como portada una de las paginas, solo en esa pagina se muestra dichas imágenes.
Todo el contenido del footer como textos, etc... se muestran normal; pero las imágenes son el problema.

**Creo que es un problema de ruta en el "src" de la imagen**; así que  mi pregunta es, **¿Que diferencia hay entre la portada y una pagina(no portada)?**, si sabemos que las paginas y portada se construyen en el mismo archivo `page.php`.

La primera sospecha que tuve es que la función `is_front_page()` que sirve para mostrar el contenido solo en la portada; este siendo aplicado junto a las imágenes; pero no es el caso.

esta es la ruta de mi imagen `src="wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"` que esta dentro del archivo `footer.php`

**seria absurdo poner un montón de código sin utilidad, porque creo que el problema es la ruta**

**¿Alguna idea?**

Comment: ¿Estas escribiendo a mano la ruta de las imagenes en el `src=`?  Si es asi prueba poniendo una barra ` /` al inicio, así:  `/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png`, asi le indicas que empiece a buscarlas en la raíz del dominio, y no a partir de la ruta actual, que quizas se encuentra en un directorio en lugar de la raiz. Vamos, un problema de rutas relativas vs absolutas.

Comment: ya lo probé; en la portada hace que desparezca el icono.png, y en la pagina normal tampoco aparece.

Comment: ¿Cual es la ruta base del wordpress?  www.dominio.com?  o mas bien www.dominio.com/blog?  Si fuera este segundo caso la ruta absoluta de la imagen seria mas bien asi:  `/blog/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png` pero entiendo que WP tiene que tener una variable que puedes poner en lugar de tener que hardcodearlo pues cada instalación del tema puede estar en cualquier parte.

Comment: lo estoy haciendo en escritorio y la ruta es:  http://localhost/cliente/

Comment: cliente es el nombre de mi carpeta wordpress

Comment: Pues prueba con `src="/cliente/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"`

Comment: woo! joder;  funciona... gracias!!!!!!!

Comment: Segun veo (no se de WP) esto te puede ayudar:  `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` a encontrar la ruta base de una instalacion de wp cualquiera, y lo podrias aplicar en el `src=`

Comment: Pero no podre serrar la pregunta, amenos que me respondas con una respuesta que incluya la ruta :)

Comment: Si, claro, pero mejor una respuesta perfecta, por eso, prueba con el `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` a ver que te devuelve, me lo dices y te pongo la respuesta completa

Comment: Segun veo `‘wpurl’ – Es la direccion de WP (URL) (establecida en Configuración > General)` por lo tanto deberias pasarle ese valor obtenido con esa función al principio de la ruta "relativa" que estabas usando.  Algo asi:  `src="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'"wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"` (aunque desconozco si eso lo puedes hacer en una template de WP o bien lo debes hacer en el codigo y luego pasarlo a una variable dentro de la plantilla html que estes usando

Comment: lo imprimí en  echo(php) y sale en la portada localhost:32  (32 es el nombre de mi portada); entonces seria asi:  src="<?php get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>/cliente/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"   ósea no cambia.

Comment: ¿Que URL tienes puesta en Configuración->General?  ¿Ninguna?  quizas debas cambiar `<?php get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>`por `<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>` y seguramente quitar el `/cliente` pues lo debes tener en la configuracion puesto. Es decir, dejarlo asi:  `src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"` y ver que pasa esta vez.

Comment: Segun veo eso de `Configuracion->General` podria estar en `Opciones->General` más bien y es el primer campo de URL que veas que pone algo asi como "URL del Wordpress"

Comment: use una plantilla para crear un tema, no construí todo; use underscores:  https://underscores.me/   la URL que me pides es: http://localhost/cliente

Comment: Perfecto pues, ahora asegurate que usas `echo get_bloginfo('wpurl')` para agregar la ruta absoluta a las imagenes y ya lo tenemos (bueno, tambien asegurate que la ruta de la imagen sin eso es absoluta tambien, es decir, que empieza con `/` así:  `/wp-content/etc...`)

Comment: no me sabia esa función lo tuve que estudiar.  Perfecto!!!  funciona muy bien... Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Respuesta ampliada** (gracias *@JefferzonBol* por tu aporte):

---

Como suele suceder, hay **varias funciones y opciones que pueden dar una respuesta correcta a esta pregunta**. Una solución posible es conseguir la ruta absoluta del Wordpress o bien del tema activo y luego corregir la ruta de las imagenes acorde a eso.

### Funciones disponibles y sus parámetros:

1. Función ***get_bloginfo($show)***: Muestra la información del parametro `$show`, que puede tener muchos [valores predefinidos distintos, que encontrarás en su documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/). En esta respuesta nos centraremos solo en dos:

- *'wpurl'*: Éste parámetro aplicado a esta función nos devuelve una URL con la ruta que está establecida dentro del admin de Wordpress, en el menú **Opciones->General** en el campo correspondiente a *URL del Wordpress*.
- *'template_url'*: Éste parámetro nos devuelve una URL con la ruta del tema **activo** en Wordpress.

La forma de forzar la salida de esta función es usando `echo`. Por ejemplo si sólo queremos la ruta del Wordpress:

```
<php echo get_bloginfo('wprul'); ?>
```

o bien si queremos toda la ruta hasta el tema activo:

```
<php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

Por otra parte, si queremos ahorrarnos el `echo` podemos usar directamente esta otra función:

2. Función ***bloginfo($show)***: Hace casi lo mismo que `get_bloginfo($show)` pero haciendo un `echo` directamente de su resultado.

De hecho [su código](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) en `wp-includes/general-template.php` es el siguiente:

```
function bloginfo( $show = '' ) {
    echo get_bloginfo( $show, 'display' );
}
```

Es por ello que la forma de usarlo no necesita el `echo`, sino simplemente:

```
<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que esta función `bloginfo()` ejecuta el `echo` directamente, por lo tanto no sirve de nada asignarla a otra variable de trabajo en caso de necesidad, pues ejecutaria el echo y no seria asignada.

Por lo tanto, conociendo estas dos funciones y sus dos posibles parámetros *relacionados con las rutas a las imagenes*, tenemos hasta **cuatro soluciones posibles** según como sea el escenario para aplicarlas.

Aquí tan solo mostraré la solución expuesta en la respuesta inicial, dejando las otras opciones como alternativas para quien las quiera probar y usar por los motivos que crea convenientes.

### **Respuesta inicial:**

Para solucionar tu problema una solución posible es agregar la ruta absoluta de tu Wordpress a la ruta absoluta de las imagenes.

Para descubrir la ruta absoluta de tu Wordpress con código PHP se usa esta función que pertenece a WP:

```
get_bloginfo('wpurl')
```

Esta función devuelve la ruta que está dentro del admin de Wordpress, en el menú **Opciones->General** en el campo correspondiente a *URL del Wordpress*.

***Pasos:***

Primero si el valor de `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` no termina en `/` deberas agregarlo a la ruta de la imagen para que también sea absoluta, es decir, debes cambiar esto:

```
src="wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"
```

por esto:

```
src="/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"
```

Y segundo, agrega `<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>` al principio del atributo  `src=` de la imagen. Para que al final quede así:

```
src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/temacreado/imagenes/icono.png"
```

Con esto deberia funcionarte en cualquier instalación de Wordpress que vaya a incluir tu tema sea cual sea la ruta que escojan en la ***URL del Wordpress*** dentro del menú **Opciones->General** del admin.

Comment: get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) Seria mas corto, <?php get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/imagenes/icono.png

Comment: @JefferzonBol: Luego edito la respuesta con eso, gracias. Le falta el `echo` a tu propuesta, tambien se lo pondré.